# Code not executing after the end of the loop; cant find the reason why the prints are not working after the loop is ended or not started even

Tags: c, loops, printing

// to calculate of N numbers entered, the number of odd and even numbers, the average of all numbers and  of the even

```
int N, nEven=0,      nOdd=0,    generalSum,      evenSum;

float   evenAverage=0,      generalAverage=0;

printf("enter as many values as needes -- insert 0 to exit \n");
N = -1;

while(N != 0){
    scanf("%d", &N);
    generalSum += N;
    
    if((N % 2 == 0) && (N != 0)){
        nEven++;
        evenSum += N;
        
    }
    if((N % 2 != 0) && (N != 0)){
        nOdd++;
    }
}

evenAverage = evenSum / nEven;
generalAverage = generalSum / (nEven + nOdd);
    

printf("number of even   -- %d \n", nEven);
printf("number of odd    -- %d \n", nOdd);
printf("even average     -- %f \n", evenAverage);
printf("general average  -- %f \n", generalAverage);
```

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run the program in a debugger and step through it line by line to see exactly what it is doing. If you still need help please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as well as the exact test input.

Answer (score 0):

- The variables `generalSum` and `evenSum` have to be initialized before adding things there if they are local variables, or their initiali values are indeterminate and using such indeterminate values invokes *undefined behavior*.
- You should be careful not to divide by zero.
- You should check if `scanf()` successfully read what is expected.

```
/* initialize generalSum and evenSum */
int N, nEven=0,      nOdd=0,    generalSum = 0,      evenSum = 0;

float   evenAverage=0,      generalAverage=0;

printf("enter as many values as needes -- insert 0 to exit \n");
N = -1;

while(N != 0){
    /* check if scanf() succeeded */
    if (scanf("%d", &N) != 1) break;
    generalSum += N;
    
    if((N % 2 == 0) && (N != 0)){
        nEven++;
        evenSum += N;
        
    }
    if((N % 2 != 0) && (N != 0)){
        nOdd++;
    }
}

/* avoid divisions by zero */
if(nEven != 0){
    evenAverage = evenSum / nEven;
}
if((nEven + nOdd) != 0){
    generalAverage = generalSum / (nEven + nOdd);
}

printf("number of even   -- %d \n", nEven);
printf("number of odd    -- %d \n", nOdd);
printf("even average     -- %f \n", evenAverage);
printf("general average  -- %f \n", generalAverage);
```

Also note that the divisions `evenSum / nEven` and `generalSum / (nEven + nOdd)` are *integer divisions* and its results are truncated to integers. You should cast (at least) one of the operands to `float` if you dont want them to be truncated.

Comment: i tried initializing one of the division variables as float, and i did not work still, i think the problem is the possible division by 0, gonna try fixing that

Comment: @AndreDoreaMendes, did you try intialising the generalSum and evenSum variables to zero in the first line of the code. I was trying to execute it on my shell, and it seems to be working fine. Can you please try that once

Answer (score 0):

I completely agree with MikeCat, you need to initialize variables before using it otherwise it will pick some garbage values.
To give you an instance of this, I tried running this on a compiler and I will be sharing the output below: -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int N, nEven=0,      nOdd=0,    generalSum,      evenSum;
    
    float   evenAverage=0,      generalAverage=0;
    
    printf("enter as many values as needes -- insert 0 to exit \n");
    N = -1;
    
    while(N != 0){
    scanf("%d", &N);
    generalSum += N;
    
    if((N % 2 == 0) && (N != 0)){
        nEven++;
        evenSum += N;
        
    }
    if((N % 2 != 0) && (N != 0)){
        nOdd++;
    }
    }
    
    evenAverage = evenSum / nEven;
    generalAverage = generalSum / (nEven + nOdd);
    
    
    printf("number of even   -- %d \n", nEven);
    printf("number of odd    -- %d \n", nOdd);
    printf("even average     -- %f \n", evenAverage);
    printf("general average  -- %f \n", generalAverage);
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Result of first Run of the same code: -**

```
enter as many values as needes -- insert 0 to exit 
12
13
09
0
number of even   -- 1 
number of odd    -- 2 
even average     -- 32777.000000 
general average  -- 604796096.000000
```

I reran the same code and you can see the results are different for the average values because of the garbage values being picked up for generalSum and evenSum variables: -

```
enter as many values as needes -- insert 0 to exit 
12
13
09
0
number of even   -- 1 
number of odd    -- 2 
even average     -- 32778.000000 
general average  -- 257441200.000000
```

Please initialize variables in c before using them.

Hope this is helpful
Please reach out in comments if any further clarification is required

Thanks